# Crear estructura de datos y recorrerla en R

Tags: r, estructuras-de-datos

Estoy tratando de leer varias hojas en Excel, cada hoja tiene un rango de datos, dependiendo de la "zona".

Es decir, tengo las siguientes hojas en Excel:

[image: Nombres de las hojas]
2005, 2009, 2008, ..., 2020.

Cada hoja tiene diferentes rangos, denominados zona, los cuales pueden ser desde 7 hasta 11 zonas distintas, dependiendo del ciclo escolar. Obviamente, cada zona está en un rango diferente dentro de la hoja, e inclusive entre las diferentes hojas. Es decir, en la hoja "ESC. 2005", tengo 7 zonas, cada una con un rango diferente:

[image: Zonas dentro de una hoja]

Por ejemplo, una zona está delimitada por una cierta región (zona1: "A11:W21"):

[image: Zona 1: Ciclo "2004-2005"]

```
zona1: "A11:W21"
zona2: "A45:W54"
...
zona7: "A215:W22"
```

Con esto, pretendo enlazar el nombre de la hoja, con el nombre del ciclo y los datos de cada rango, por lo que debería quedar una estructura así:

Nombre de la Hoja de Excel, Ciclo Escolar, Número de Zona, Rango de los datos de la zona.

```
"ESC. 2005", "2004-2005", 1, "A11:W21"
"ESC. 2006", "2005-2006", 2, "A45:W222"
...
"ESC. 2020", "2019-2020", 10, "A249:Ww56"
```

Aunque, como se ve, los nombres de la hoja y el ciclo, se repiten dependiendo de el número de zonas que existe en cada ciclo, cosa que veo innecesario.

La idea principal es enlazar todos estos datos para que se los pueda pasar a una función que vaya recorriendo cada hoja con el total de sus zonas. Es decir, que aparezca una vez el nombre de la hoja, una vez el nombre del ciclo y la cantidad necesarias de zonas. Algo así:

```
"ESC. 2005"
    "2004-2005"
        1, "A11:W21"
        2, "A45:W53"
        ...
        7: "A215:W222"
...
"ESC. 2020"
    "2019-2020"
        1, "A11:Q18"
        2, "A38:Q44"
        ...
        11, "A309:Q314"
```

Hasta el momento, sólo se me ocurre hacer una lista con los vectores, de la siguiente manera:

```r
    datos_05_18 <- list(
      # Hoja: ESC. 2005, con 7 zonas
      c("ESC. 2005", "2004-2005", 1, "A11:W21"),
      c("ESC. 2005", "2004-2005", 2, "A45:W54"),
      c("ESC. 2005", "2004-2005", 3, "A79:W87"),
      c("ESC. 2005", "2004-2005", 4, "A113:W124"),
      c("ESC. 2005", "2004-2005", 5, "A147:W158"),
      c("ESC. 2005", "2004-2005", 6, "A181:W189"),
      c("ESC. 2005", "2004-2005", 7, "A215:W222"),
      ...
      # Hoja: ESC. 2018, con 10 zonas
      c("ESC. 2018", "2017-2018", 1, "A10:W20"),
      c("ESC. 2018", "2017-2018", 2, "A43:W51"),
      c("ESC. 2018", "2017-2018", 3, "A71:W78"),
      c("ESC. 2018", "2017-2018", 4, "A98:W105"),
      c("ESC. 2018", "2017-2018", 5, "A122:W129"),
      c("ESC. 2018", "2017-2018", 6, "A147:W154"),
      c("ESC. 2018", "2017-2018", 7, "A174:W181"),
      c("ESC. 2018", "2017-2018", 8, "A200:W205"),
      c("ESC. 2018", "2017-2018", 9, "A224:W231"),
      c("ESC. 2018", "2017-2018", 10, "A249:W256")
    )
```

La función que lee los datos, es la siguiente:

```r
    # Función para leer los datos desde Excel
    # Parámetros:
    #   hoja: str <- Nombre de la hoja del libro.
    #   ciclo_escolar: str <- El ciclo escolar al que pertenecen
    #                 los datos
    #   zona_escolar: str <- Zona a la que pertenecen los datos
    #   rango: str <- Rango de celdas al que pertenecen los datos, se
    #          escriben de la forma "A1:W21"
    leer_excel <- function(hoja = "", ciclo_escolar = "",
                           zona_escolar = 0, rango = "" ) {
      # Si el nombre de la hoja es nulo, se regresa un error
      if (hoja == "") {
        return("Debe indicar el nombre de una hoja del libro de Excel")
      }
      
      # Se leen los datos del arhivo de Excel, definido en la variable
      # xlsx_file, en la hoja indicada, en un rango determinado,
      # se indica que las filas no tienen nombre, y se agrega que,
      # en caso de encontrar el caracter '-' (guión), se considere
      # como NA (Not Available)
      df <- read_excel(xlsx_file, sheet = hoja,
                 range = rango, col_names = F, 
                 na = "-")
    
      # Se agregan dos columnas al dataset, ciclo y zona [escolares]
      df <- cbind(df, ciclo = ciclo_escolar, zona = zona_escolar)
      
      # La función regresa el dataframe
      return(df)
    }
```

Así es como llamo a la funcion:

```r
    # Inicializamos el data frame en blanco
    df_05_18 <- data.frame()
    # Recorremos toda la lista de datos_05_18
    for (i in seq(1:length(datos_05_18))) {
      # Leemos, rango por rango, dentro de una determinada hoja
      df <- leer_excel(datos_05_18[[i]][[1]], datos_05_18[[i]][[2]],
                       datos_05_18[[i]][[3]], datos_05_18[[i]][[4]])
      
      # Agregamos todos los dataframe a uno sólo para facilitar
      # la manipulación de los datos
      df_05_18 <- rbind(df_05_18, df)
    }
```

Se supone que debería poder pasar, una sola vez, el nombre de la hoja y el ciclo y que vaya leyendo la estructura con los datos de cada rango de celdas, representativas de la zona, independientemente de su tamaño.

¿Existe una forma efectiva de solucionar esto?

Comment: Bienvenido/a Will! Aunque tu descripción es muy detallada no creo posible que obtengas una respuesta concreta sin un ejemplo de tus datos. Si esos datos son públicos sería buena idea poner un enlace. Sobre todo porque no hay dos exceles que tengan los mismos problemas. También ayudaría editar la pregunta mencionando el objetivo que tienes ¿es identificar las zonas? ¿es generar una estructura de datos en R con los datos que están en esos rangos de la hoja de Excel?

Comment: Muchas gracias @mpaladino. He agregado algunas imágenes y parte del código que utilizo para leer el archivo Excel.